# API Design - Use object or collection as parameter?

Tags: java, oop, api-design

Which one of the following designs is considered better for an API and why?

`apiMethod(Map<A, B> aToB)`

or

`apiMethod(MapWrapper<A, B> mapWrapper)`
where `MapWrapper` is simply a class containing a reference to the Map.

What are the pros and cons of both the approaches?

Comment: I'd prefer having a model class as parameter, rather than a generic `Map`. `MapWrapper` also does not make sense - which added value would it have agains `Map`?

Comment: The first one, adding a wrapper makes no sense. Probably a better design than using a map is possible.

Comment: what is that map responsible for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always strive for "minimalistic" APIs.

In this case: when your API works when passing a **Map** - then of course you choose that path. Why put the burden on your client to first *wrap* that map?!

The pro of option 1 is - this is the straight forward path.

Whereas option 2 only has the downside of making it harder to use the API.

In other words: if the *central* "property" of that parameter is "to be a map" - then it should be passed as map. But when the "central theme" is something different - then you pass something that goes along that other theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a `Map` as a parameter of API is bad practice because it's very difficult to understand what does your API really need. In some ancient code I found method like:

```
doSomeStuff(Session session){
  String aa = session.get("aa");
  String bb = session.get("bb");
  return aa + bb;
}
```

The refactoring of this code will be:

```
doSomeStuff(String aa, String bb){
  return aa + bb;
}
```

and you know that you need `aa` and `bb` to call your API.